# MODX - Making multiple snippet calls on a page returning differeny output

Tags: modx

I've created a snippet that pulls data from a databse table and displays it in tabular format. The snippet takes an id as parameter, and this is added to the sql query.

My problem is that if I've got more than 1 snippet call (sometimes need the tabular data for different id's displayed on a page) on the same page, all table data is the same as the last database call that's been made by the last snippet.

What do I need to do to kinda not cache the snippet database calls and have them all display their own content?

I've tried setting the page to no cache-able. Also used the [! !] brackets for the snippet calls, and even used the function_exists() method, but none of them helped.

Please can someone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end of the snippet:

```
mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('db_name');
```

You need to specify the connection parameters ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to answer if you can post your snippet. I do this with multiple calls on the page without issue, so there is either something wrong inside the snippet, or you need to output to unique placeholder names.

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered a glitch of ModX, and it took me a long time to solve. ModX does a lot of caching by using hashing and apparently, when multiple connections are made from within one page divided over multiple snippets,  this erratic behaviour can be seen. This is most likely very unwanted behaviour, it can be solved easily but gives you terrible headache otherways.

One sympton is that `$modx->getObject($classname, $id)`returns null (often).

The solution is very simple:
either use a static class with a single db instance, or
use `$modx->setPlaceholder($instance, $tag);`, or a combination.

My solution has been:

```
class dt__xpdo {

  private function __construct() {}

  public function __destruct() {
    $this->close();
  }

  static public function db($modx = null) {

    if ($modx->getPlaceholder('dt_xpdo') == '') {
      $dt_user   = 'xxxxxxxxx';
      $dt_pw     = 'xxxxxxxxx';
      $dt_host   = 'localhost';
      $dt_dbname = 'xxxxxxxxx';
      $dt_port   = '3306';

      $dt_dsn = "mysql:host=$dt_host;dbname=$dt_dbname;port=$dt_port;charset=utf8";

      $dt_xpdo = new xPDO($dt_dsn, $dt_user, $dt_pw);

      $dt_xpdo->setPackage('mymodel', MODX_CORE_PATH.'components/mymodel/'.'model/', '');

      //$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, 'mymodel.config.php');
      //$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, 'Could not addPackage for mymodel!');

      $modx->setPlaceholder('dt_xpdo', $dt_xpdo);
    }

    return $modx->getPlaceholder('dt_xpdo');
  }
}
```

Now you can use in your code:

`require_once 'above.php';`

and use something like

`$xpdo = dt__xpdo::db($modx);`

and continue flawlessly!